# Generic Method That Takes an interface that implements another interface, not calling correct method

Tags: c#, interface

I am create a self searching assembly, that has an ISearchable interface that can be implemented. It also provides the ability to search on a phone number so it has an IPhoneNumberSearchable that implements ISearchable.  I then go through the assembly looking for anything that implements the IPhoneNumberSearchable and call Search. If the class implements IPhoneNumberSearchable  and ISearchable it will only call the ISearchable method. Any ideas on how to make this work? Code Follows

```
public class SearchManager
{



    private ISearchItem[] Search<T>(string searchValue) where T: class,ISearchable
    {

        Assembly current = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        IEnumerable<T> instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                        where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))
                                 && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                        select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as T;

        var list = new List<ISearchItem>();
        foreach (T item in instances)
        {
            try
            {
                T i = item as T;
                list.AddRange(item.Search(searchValue));
            }
            catch (System.Exception) { }
        }


        return list.ToArray();

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the specified search value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchValue">The search value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISearchItem[] Search(string searchValue)
    {
        return Search<ISearchable>(searchValue);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for phone number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber">The phone number.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISearchItem[] SearchForPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return Search<IPhoneSearchable>(phoneNumber);
    }

}


/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public interface ISearchable
{

    ISearchItem[] Search(string searchValue);
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public interface ISearchable
{

    ISearchItem[] Search(string searchValue);
}



public class CustomerManager : Search.IPhoneSearchable,Search.ISearchable
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the specified phone number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber">The phone number.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Search.ISearchItem[] Search.IPhoneSearchable.Search(string phoneNumber)
    {
        //Search based upon phone number            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the specified search value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchValue">The search value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Search.ISearchItem[] Search.ISearchable.Search(string searchValue)
    {
        //Search on anything code
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a solution to your problem, but have a look at MEF - it looks like you are re-inventing the wheel: http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This code does not work as You expect, because it work precisely according to the Language specification.

Basically in You class CustomManager You implement ISearchable implicitly and explicitly. When YOu want to try to call this method in a regular code (not using the reflection) it looks like that

```
CustomManager k = new CustomManager();
IPhoneSearchable x = k;
x.Search("strings"); //calls IPhoneSearchable.Search()
ISearchable y = k;
y.Search("string"); //calls ISearchable.Search()
k.Search("string); //calls ISearchable.Search()!!!
```

the reason for this precisely not to confuse the coder. You implement the interface in a class so each call to this method should call this implementation. If for some other reason You implement another interface explicitly You need to specify that You want this precise call to happen.

I do not want to intefere with Your design but for me this looks a bit weird. One method searches for something, and the other searches for specific stuff, but both have the same signature while providing slightly different functionality. Maybe It should be changed that `IPhoneSearchable` provides a method called

```
SearchPhones(string[] filters)
```

that actually calls a method Search thus hiding implementation details from the user. By providing an Inteface IPhoneSearchable you do nothing in the contract specification other that providing a marker interface.

So to fix Your code You should probably create a collection of actual MethodCalls (hence CustomManager has two method calls that is Search from ISearchable and Search from IPhoneSearchable)

and the iterate this collection and call each method.

regards
Luke

Comment: Actually `k.Search("something")` does not exist :)

Comment: Sorry AS CII indeed I thought that there was implicit method implementation. There indeed is no k.Search("Something")

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons explained by luckyluke your code won't work. But, instead of creating

> a collection of actual MethodCalls (hence CustomManager has two method calls that is Search from ISearchable and Search from IPhoneSearchable) and then iterate this collection and call each method

you could do something like this (I have slightly changed your code):

```
public interface ISearch
{
    IEnumerable<string> Search(string filter);
}

public interface IPhoneSearch : ISearch
{
    new IEnumerable<string> Search(string filter);
}

public class Searchable : IPhoneSearch
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Search(string filter)
    {
        yield return "Phone!";
    }

    IEnumerable<string> ISearch.Search(string filter)
    {
        yield return "Normal!";
    }
}
```

And then in your searcher:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Search<T>(string searchValue) where T : class, ISearch
{
    var current = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    where !t.IsInterface
                    where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                    select (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    foreach (var item in instances)
    {
        foreach (var occurrence in item.Search(searchValue))
        {
            yield return occurrence;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway I would suggest to change this implementation, as luckyluke said.

Comment: Your points are valid ASCII, What we don't know is that if he wants to Call only Phone Search or the Search or Both (hence I suggested method Call collection).And +1 for using IsAssignalbleFrom (such a clear thing, but slightly differnt approach - but it's possible that he has implicit conversions..

Comment: Yes I want to be able to call them separately I also wanted the ability to define one or both. My main issue was even though the generic type was the IPhoneSearchable, when I called search upon the generic type(IPhoneSearchable) it still called the ISearchable method.

Answer (score 0):

My main issue was even though the generic type was the IPhoneSearchable, when I called search upon the generic type(IPhoneSearchable) it still called the ISearchable method.

The only way I could get it to work was through reflection using the following code to call search.

```
        var list = new List<ISearchItem>();
        foreach (T item in instances)
        {


            try
            {

                var type = typeof(T);

                var inter = item.GetType().GetInterface(type.Name);

                var results = (ISearchItem[])inter.InvokeMember("Search", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null, item, new object[] { searchValue });
                if(results != null)
                    list.AddRange(results);
            }
            catch (System.Exception) { }
        }
```